# vba syntax error when writing sumif formula

Tags: vba, excel, syntax

I try to write this line of code in VBA as the following:

```
Range("S5")="=SUMIF(L2:L793,">=0")"
```

However, there is a syntax error when I try to run the code.
The error is highlighted as ")". 
Hope someone can help with this problem!

Comment: A " inside "" needs to be escaped to "": `Range("S5").Formula = "=SUMIF(L2:L793,"">=0"")"`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is in the escaping of the `"` sign. In general, this is an easy way to "translate" any Excel formula to VBA:

1. Write the formula in Excel, thus it works ok.
2. Select the cell with the formula.
3. Run this code:

---

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

---

4. Take a look at the immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>G</kbd>).